# Can I use Resharper 2.0 to inspect code issues in my project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring, resharper, windows-ce

I use Resharper on my personal Windows 8 / VS 2012 projects.

I'm also using Resharper at work, both with VS 2010 (Resharper 7.1) and with VS 2003 in XP Mode on a Windows 7 machine (Resharper 2.0).

A funny thing happened on the way to refactorville this morning, though: I searched in vain in the Resharper (2.0) windows for my beloved Inspect | Code Issues in Current Project command - and not only is it nowhere to be seen, but it seems that there is nothing analagous there. Is there a similar functionality in 2.0 that I'm somehow missing? If so, how do I invoke it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official [**Code Quality Analysis**](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_analysis.html) Feature Page, under the [**Find Code Issues**](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_analysis.html#Find_Code_Issues) section (emphasis mine):

> **ReSharper 5 and higher** lets you view all ReSharper code highlights —
>   code quality issues, redundancies, language usage opportunities, and
>   code improvement suggestions — from a single tool window called
>   Inspection Results. That's much easier than navigating through your
>   code files one by one to find and remove issues.
>
> To display this tool window, choose Inspect | Code Issues in Solution
>   or Inspect | Code Issues in Current Project on the ReSharper menu.
>   Alternatively, select a node in the Solution Explorer, right-click it,
>   and choose Find Code Issues.

It appears to be a newer feature available only in ReSharper 5+.

Comment: So it makes me wonder what value Resharper 2.0 has - what does it do?

Comment: I did actually find this: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/releaseNotes20.html.  That's the release notes for 2.0, and on the right side, there are links to Resharper 2-specific resources, such as "Overview" which tells of the features in that version.